# Creating a scipy-dev environment

Tags: python, scipy, conda

I am following [steps in the contributor guide](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/contributor/conda_guide.html#conda-guide) to create a development environment. I am up to step 2.

> The Python-level dependencies for building SciPy will be installed as part of the conda environment creation - see environment.yml
>
> Note that we’re installing SciPy’s build dependencies and some other software, but not (yet) SciPy itself. Also note that you’ll need to have this virtual environment active whenever you want to work with the development version of SciPy.
>
> To create the environment with all dependencies and compilers, from the root of the SciPy folder, do
>
> `conda env create -f environment.yml`

However this gives an error that the environment file does not exist.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/environment.yml <-- environment.yml should look like this, so I have copied and put an environment.yml file in the `envs` folder.

I am unsure whether I should put this file in the envs folder or if I need to go to the root of the scipy version that already exist in my pkgs folder.

```
C:\\Users\\micha\\anaconda3\\envs\>conda env create -f environment.yml

EnvironmentFileNotFound: 'C:\\Users\\micha\\anaconda3\\envs\\environment.yml' file not found
```

After inserting the environment.yml file:

```
C:\\Users\\micha\\anaconda3\\envs\>conda env create -f environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
```

I am still awaiting the reults, however not sure if I have done the correct thing with the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the environment file is, one just needs to ensure the *path* they provide exists. In fact, Conda can even create it from a URL:

```bash
conda env create -f https://github.com/scipy/scipy/raw/main/environment.yml
```

Note that most users find it useful to name their environments by passing an `--name,-n` argument (see `conda env create --help`). This is arbitrary, so pick something semantic/easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction is to run that command `from the root of the SciPy folder`.  The "SciPy folder" is what you just checked out, and the root is the top-level folder of that checkout.  Doing this all from the command-line would look something like:

```
C:\Users\User> git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
[git output omitted]
C:\Users\User> cd scipy
C:\Users\User\scipy> conda env create -f environment.yml
```

That root folder is also where you'll run the "dev.py" script from.